# Need explanation of tcl regexp inline example in the man page please

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, tcl, inline

While trying to understand  regexp and --inline use, saw this example but couldn't understand how it works.

Link to the man page is: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm#M13
In there, under --inline option, this example was given:

```
 regexp -inline -- {\w(\w)} " inlined "
 => {in n}
regexp -all -inline -- {\w(\w)} " inlined "
 => {in n li i ne e}
```

How does this "{\w(\w)}" yield "{in n}"?  Can someone explain please.
Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If `-inline` but not `-all` is not given, `regexp` returns a list consisting of one value for the entire region matched and one value for each submatch (regions captured by parentheses). To see what the entire match is, ignore the parentheses: the pattern is now `{\w\w}`, matching the two first word characters in the string (`in`). The first submatch is what you get if you skip one word character (the `\w` outside the parentheses) and then capture the next word character (the `\w` inside the parentheses), getting `n`.

If both `-inline` and `-all` are given, `regexp` does this repeatedly, restarting at the first character beyond the last entire match.

Answer (score 2):

I think that to understand `-inline`, you must first understand that `-inline` puts the matches (and submatches) in a list. Because if you had...

```
regexp -- {\w(\w)} " inlined " m1 m2
```

You will have...

```
% puts $m1
in
% puts $m2
n
```

As the whole match `in` is stored in `m1` while the submatch of the capture group `n` is stored in `m2`.

Putting those in a list (i.e. when using `-inline`) will give `{in n}`.

When you now have `-all` and `-inline` at the same time (assuming that you already know that `-all` retrieves all non-overlapping matches in regexp), you can no more use variable names after the input string, so you get a list containing all the matches and submatches and if I have to name them `m` and `s` (for match and submatch respectively), you have:

```
in n  li i  ne e
m  s  m  s  m  s
```